# Console log showing mismatched value

Tags: console

When I select the first image, the "out" shows undefined & "in" shows the byte array result.
But after selecting the second image, "out" prints the byte array value of **previous** image & "in" shows the result of second(current) image.

```
upload(files: any) {
        console.log('jj');
        const file = files.files[0];
        if (!file) return;
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = (event) => {
          this.url = reader.result;
          var base64Index = this.url.indexOf(';base64,') + ';base64,'.length;
          var base64 = this.url.substring(base64Index);
          var raw = window.atob(base64);
          var rawLength = raw.length;
          let imgArray = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));
          for (let i = 0; i < rawLength; i++) {
            imgArray[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
          }
          this.imgArrayy = imgArray;
          console.log("in", this.imgArrayy);
        }
        console.log("out", this.imgArrayy);
      }
```

**Console output:-**
[image]

**How can I get the correct value for each corresponding image?**

Answer (score 0):

The readAsDataURL is an async function. That means the code may not execute in order.

The sequence of your code is:

- schedule the readAsDataURL
- print console.log out
- execute the onload
- print console.log in

console.log out is run before onLoad. Therefore the console.log out is undefined.

Is it typescript? I am not sure the syntax.
But the idea is change the upload function to async and use await to wait for the completion of file read.

Or you can change upload to async but use FileReaderSync instead. https://www.javascripture.com/FileReaderSync

Then, the sequence of code will be:

- schedule the readAsDataURL
- wait until readAsDataURL completed
- execute the onload & print console.log in
- print console.log out

To fix this, you can try:

```
const obj = {hello: 'world'};
const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)], {type : 'application/json'});

async function upload(files) {
  console.log('jj');
  const file = files.files[0];
  if (!file) return;
  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (event) => {
      this.url = reader.result;
      var base64Index = this.url.indexOf(';base64,') + ';base64,'.length;
      var base64 = this.url.substring(base64Index);
      var raw = window.atob(base64);
      var rawLength = raw.length;
      let imgArray = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));
      for (let i = 0; i < rawLength; i++) {
        imgArray[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
      }
      this.imgArrayy = imgArray;
      console.log("in", this.imgArrayy);
      resolve(reader.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
  console.log("out", this.imgArrayy);
}

upload({files:[blob]});
```

output

```
jj
VM532:20 in Uint8Array(22) [123, 10, 32, 32, 34, 104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 34, 58, 32, 34, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100, 34, 10, 125]
VM532:25 out Uint8Array(22) [123, 10, 32, 32, 34, 104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 34, 58, 32, 34, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100, 34, 10, 125]
```